# Can I dispatch vuex action inside getter function?

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I want to dispatch action inside getter function.

1. Is it possible and right.

2. If yes how can I do it?

I guess it will be something like this dispatch('GET_BOOKS');

```
const getters = {
    getAllBooksDispatch: (state, getters, dispatch) => {
        if (state.books === null) {
            dispatch('GET_BOOKS');
        }
        return state.books
    },
};
```

But it does not work.

So my store file looks like this.

```
const initialState = {
    books: null
};

const getters = {
    getAllBooksDispatch: (state, getters, dispatch) => {
        if (state.books === null) {
            dispatch('GET_BOOKS');
        }
        return state.books
    },
};

const mutations = {
    SET_BOOKS: (state,{data}) => {
        console.log('SET_BOOKS mutations')
        state.books = data;
    },
};

const actions = {
    GET_BOOKS: async ({ commit }) => {
        let token = users.getters.getToken;

        let query = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            axios.get(config.api + 'books', {token}).then(({data}) => {
                if (data) {
                    commit('SET_BOOKS', {data: data})
                    resolve()
                } else {
                    reject(data.message);
                }
            }).catch(() => {
                reject('Error sending request to server!');
            })
        })

    },
};
```

Comment: Elaborate _"but it does not work"_, please.

Answer (score 3):

No, you can't. At least not the way you want to. The third argument in a getter is the `rootState` object when using modules, not `dispatch`. Even if you find a way to dispatch an action inside a getter it won't work the way you expect. Getters must be synchronous, but actions can be (and in this example are) asynchronous. In your example, `GET_BOOKS` would be dispatched but the getter would still return `state.books` as null.

I'd recommend handling this sort of lazy-loading outside of the Vuex store.